# 404.0 when I create a site collection and "Updates are currently disallowed on GET requests" when opening General Settings

Tags: sharepoint-server, iis

I've just installed **Sharepoint Server 2019** on top of **Windows Server 2019 Datacenter**.

After installing the following URL was opened automatically: `http://myservername:16607/_admin/createsite.aspx?scenarioId=adminconfig&instanceId=my-guid`. As far as I understand, it's a wizard for initial setup.

During the wizard it was proposed to me to create a new site collection. For testing purposes, I created one named *msc*, with the following settings:

[image]

The collection was created successfully, but when I try opening `http://myservername/sites/msc`, I see an error page **HTTP 404.0 — Not Found**. (The code is 0x80070002). Where can I look at to fix the problem?

**Additional information**:

When I try opening **General Settings** for **Sharepoint - 80**, I see the following error:

[image]

**General Settings** for SharePoint Central Administration works fine.